# List of resources?

Tags: feature-request

I notice many people ask questions similar to:

- Where can I find a list of full/new moons?
- When does the sun/moon rise/set in my area on a given date?
- How do I compute planetary/lunar positions very accurately?
- How do I convert ra/dec to alt/az

and so on. Should we post a list of links to external resources (eg, HORIZONS and other NASA pages) somewhere, and, if so, where?

Answer (score 4):

When someone asks a question which folks are likely to ask over and over, you should use that opportunity to **create a really awesome, canonical answer** to make this an invaluable resource on the Internet.

For example, if someone were to ask when the sun/moon rise/set on a given date, don't give them the time or answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, step-by-step, ultra-clear guide with screenshots and examples. Really teach folks looking for that information how to find or derive that information for themselves.

That's how you build up a body of answers to common questions in Astronomy. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines. And if you can provide great answers to those questions, you stand a great chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

You can't really do that with a single page with a list of links.